# AR quiver with shaded regions

Tags: diagrams, draw, xy-pic

I wonder how I can **shade** regions of a diagram like in the following picture (taken from p.186 of "Elements of representation theory of algebras I")

[image]

I guess people would come up with solutions using `tikz`, which would be fine, but I'm also interested to know if there is a solution using `xypic`.

Answer (score 1):

With Ti*k*Z it is not very hard.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,fit,patterns.meta,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=small,execute at end picture={
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\typeout{pft,\tikzcdmatrixname}
\path let \p1=($(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-5)-(\tikzcdmatrixname-3-3)$),
    \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in
     node[ellipse,draw,fit=(\tikzcdmatrixname-3-3)(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-5),
        rotate fit=\n1,inner ysep=-4ex,inner xsep=-1ex,
        pattern={Lines[angle=45]},pattern color=gray]{}
    node[ellipse,draw,fit=(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-3),
        inner ysep=-0.5ex,inner xsep=-0.5ex,
        pattern=Dots]{}
    node[ellipse,draw,fit=(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1),
        inner ysep=-0.5ex,inner xsep=-0.5ex,
        pattern={Lines[angle=45]},pattern color=gray]{}
        ;
\end{scope}}]
 100\arrow[dr] & & 010\arrow[dr] & & 001\\
  & 110\arrow[dr]\arrow[ur] & & 011\arrow[ur] & \\
  & & 111\arrow[ur] & & \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]